# Counting number of non-sleeping processes of a given user

Tags: command-line, bash, users, process, ps

I would like to count the number of non-sleeping processes started by a given user. I know that the sleeping processes are the ones with "S" or "D" in their `ps` status variable. I also know I can count processes from a list containing variables `user` and `state` by:

`ps -e -o user,state | grep -c 'username'`

Similarly, I know I could count the sleeping processes by:

`ps -e -o user,state | grep -c 'S|D'`

However, I can't figure it out how to use both information to count the non-sleeping processes started by the user `username`.

Comment: The answer of @PerlDuck already states how to grep for a user-name and combine this with a state not S or D.

I am a bit uncertain what you try to read out. The number of tasks running can't be higher than the number of your cores. And with tasks scheduling quite frequently you just get a snap-shot of the moment in time you are running ps.
You might want to edit your question so we can learn what you really try to achieve.

For completeness, the other possible states of a task as listed on man7 you might want to consider are I, T, t, X, Z
http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ps.1.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the output of the command

```
ps -e -o user,state
```

the state is the last character in each line. So we basically
count the lines that contain the given username and then 
neither end in an `S` nor in a `D`:

```
ps -e -o user,state | grep -c -E 'pduck.*[^SD]$'
```

This will find (or count) all lines that contain the word `pduck`
(my username) and don't end in `S` or `D`.

The `-E` is neccessary so `grep` understands the regular expression.

[@steeldriver](https://askubuntu.com/users/178692/steeldriver) suggested 
in a comment to *"select the user with `-u pduck` and omit 
it from the list of output fields altogether"*. I agree, this is even better,
but we then need to drop the `-e` switch because that would select all
processes (not only those of user `pduck`):

```
ps -u pduck -o state | grep -c -E '[^SD]$'
```